# Vertical asp.net MVC organization and VirtualPathProviders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, razor, virtualpathprovider

I'm currently working on a relatively large MVC project I would like to organize vertically.

[Why break convention?](http://www.paulstovell.com/horizontal-vertical-project-structure)
And, in more detail [here](http://codebetter.com/robashton/2011/06/13/finding-a-balance-with-asp-net-mv/)

As far as implementation goes, the plan is a [VirtualPathProvider](http://coderjournal.com/2009/05/creating-your-first-mvc-viewengine/). My question is, what would the best way be to give this VirtualPathProvider knowledge of the feature folder names?

e.g. ~/Features/{Feature}/View1.cshtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to do this, I would definately NOT use a VirtualPathProvider.  The reason is that path searches are expensive.  The more paths you have, the longer it takes to find them.

I would instead specify paths directly.  You lose the convention aspect, but you gain performance.

Comment: So, just to clarify, you mean specify each of the View paths individually? If this is the case, areas are probably a more elegant solution. I was thinking it might be as simple as the controllers inheriting from a feature-specific base controller or something along those lines.

Comment: A VirutalPathProvider provdes the paths that are searched when you specify a view without a path.  If you have a lot of paths, it takes time to search them.  The more paths, the longer it takes.  It all depends on how many paths you intend to have.